# Skaffold Kustomize Passing External Environment Variable into kustomization.yaml

Tags: skaffold, kustomize

Is there a way I can pass external environment variable to kustomization.yaml from `Skaffold`.

Assuming i have a kustomization file below

```
  resources:
    - ./deployment.yaml
    - ./service.yaml

  images:
    - name: abc
      newName: <external environment>
      newTag: <external environment>
```

I have environment exported with Image name and tag and would like to pass into the `kustomization.yaml` when executing `skaffold deploy` or `dev`

Is there a way to do this or if any solution or workaround to pass an external environment variable into `kustomization.yaml` ?

I know i can actually use `kustomize edit set image` but is ugly because i need to get the old image name to set which I try to avoid.  I wanted a simpler solution.  I couldn't find any where that says `kustomize` can use environtment variable from system like `docker-compose` that uses `${VAR}` or `skaffold` that uses `{{.VAR}}` when trying to access system environment variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, Kustomize is able to parse/replace environmental variables only in places where it is designed to. it is not a "system wide" feature and as far as i know it works only for config map generators.
Said that there is a workaround

if for example you have you kustomization.yaml in /overlays/staging folder

```yaml
  resources:
    - ./deployment.yaml
    - ./service.yaml

  images:
    - name: abc
      newName: $IMAGE_NAME
      newTag: $IMAGE_TAG
```

you can, from bash

```sh
export $IMAGE_NAME=my-app-image
export $IMAGE_TAG=latest
kubectl kustomize overlays/staging | envsubst | kubectl apply -f -
```

or equivalent oneliner.

The trick is to use `kubectl kustomize`  to generate the full kustomization (which still include the variable names not valorized), it will output on stdout and pipe it in `envsubst` which will replace every previously `export`ed variable in the text piped in, then pipe out again to `kubectl apply -f`, which this time will apply it with the trailing `-` (wich will make it read the yaml from stdin)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm aware of this solution after asking from stackoverflow.  Thanks for answering this.   I remember back in my days when testing `envsubst`, the standard binary that comes with the OS does not support default value, example, `${IMAGE_NAME:-somename}`.  The following enchanced `envsubst` does support default value `https://github.com/a8m/envsubst` .